# Remove user and password at login in Debian 9 Stretch

Tags: debian, login, lxde, beagleboneblack

I am working on a project using BeagleBone Black and an LCD cape.

For that, I downloaded the current BBB IOT image from their website and installed LXDE for user interface.

I want to create an application that starts at boot on the LCD.

I need to remove the login step at the startup. I think that LightDM is used as a desktop manager (maybe helps), but for now I only succeeded to auto insert the username.

My question is how I can pass this step without any other user intervention.

[image: Login]

Comment: Why do you need a desktop manager at all? A typical user interface on such a device just uses one full screen window and only needs X11 (for this kind of usage it even makes sense to drop X11 and directly use `/dev/fb0`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Edit your `lightdm` configuration file:

```
sudo nano /etc/pam.d/lightdm
```

Before the `@include common-auth` line , add the following line :

```
auth sufficient pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup nopasswdlogin
```

2) Create a `nopasswdlogin` group:

```
sudo addgroup --system nopasswdlogin
```

3) Add the user `USER` to `nopasswdlogin`:

```
sudo adduser USER nopasswdlogin
```

4) Add the following line on the top of your `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` configuration file:

```
[SeatDefaults]
autologin-user=USER
autologin-user-timeout=0
```

Answer (score 2):

You will want to set up auto-login in LightDM's configuration in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`; specifically, uncomment (remove the `#`s from) the following lines:

```
[SeatDefaults]
autologin-user=REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_USERNAME
autologin-user-timeout=0
```

That and other information can be found at https://wiki.debian.org/LightDM

Comment: Good point, added auto-login specific information from the page to my answer.

Comment: From link above: "It is possible to provide the user with selection of available user accounts. The most recently used login name will be selected in the list. The user still has to enter password to login." So after doing the modifications, the login screen will still appear on LCD.